# Does an activated complex have a specific heat capacity?

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetic-theory, non-equilibrium

An example of an activated complex is two atoms so close (due to collision or attraction) that they are both in the highest energy state before reaching the lowest energy state at which they can be considered to be bonded. Can the notion of a specific heat capacity be applied to such a non-equilibrium state? More formally, can we even say that an increase of temperature of x-degrees will increase the energy of the activated state y-number of eV? My intuition is that the activation energy (difference in energy of the non-bonded and activated states) is independent of temperature and therefore the notion of specific heat capacity doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

The notion of heat capacity can only be applied if the notion of 'temperature' is well-defined.  In the case of a complex containing only, say, two atoms, you cannot define a (statistical mechanical) temperature no matter what state they're in, because there are too few degrees of freedom.

Regarding activation energies: they are specifically measured between the local minima (what you are referring to as the 'equilibrium' state), so the question is somewhat void anyway.